# How Go is memory safe?

Tags: go, segmentation-fault

In the below code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    str := "abc"
    for i := 0; i <= len(str); i++ {
        fmt.Println(str[i])
    }
}
```

---

Go allows to have invalid memory access until runtime:

```
$ bin/cs61a 
97
98
99
panic: runtime error: index out of range [3] with length 3

Go fails to avoid invalid memory access until runtime.
```

---

How Go is memory safe to avoid invalid memory access?

Comment: https://medium.com/a-journey-with-go/go-memory-safety-with-bounds-check-1397bef748b5#:~:text=Go%20makes%20the%20lives%20of,safe%20access%20to%20the%20memory.

Comment: Note that it didn't let you access invalid memory. It panicked.

Comment: It avoids invalid memory access by panicking instead. The compiler adds a length check to ensure that you do not access beyond the bounds of the underlying array; when you do, rather than segfault or garbage data (a true invalid memory access), it panics and crashes the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How Go is memory safe to avoid invalid memory access?

By not having pointer arithmetics and by protecting any memory access as your code properly shows.

Comment: Yes, pointer artihmetic in C access invalid memory as valid. OK. But, crossing array boundary is handled in C similar to GO

Comment: @overexchange No, it is not.

Comment: Are you referring to array boundary access or pointer artithmetic? For array boundary, In C, OS gives SEGFAULT 11, But In GO, Is see, Go runtime is giving the error, but I don't know, if this invalid access has reached at OS level

Comment: @overexchange: accessing outside the bounds of your array isn't handled at all in C, because there is no such things as the "bounds" of the array. You only get a SIGSEGV from the OS if you access invalid memory, you can incorrectly access your process's memory all you want.

Comment: you are right, C prints the value in the invalid memory location, after crossing the boundary unlike Java & GO.

Comment: @overexchange if it reached OS level, it would segfault. Go compile adds runtime bounds checking when needed.

Comment: @Adrian Yes you are right, SIGSEGV occurs, if access crossed ~4 GB virtual address space of process memory in 32 bit machine

Comment: @overexchange, no, `SIGSEGV` means your process attempted to access _any_ address range for which it does not have a valid mapping. But that's besides the point others have tried to make. C does not handle out-of-bounds errors: if a _logically_ incorrect memory access happens to hit a legally mapped memory region, no error will be produced at runtime. So `SIGSEGV` happens when there is both a logical error in the program _and_ it so happens that the memory region to be accessed is invalid on the process management level.